# Excel Chart X Axis Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to create a line chart in Excel with the following values from my sheet:

(0,100)
(1,90)
(2,80)
(4,70)
(8,60)
(16,50)

The problem I can't work around is that I want the 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 to be both labels on the x-axis of my chart as well as the values (i.e., the 4 should be twice the distance from 0 as the 2, the 8 twice the 4, etc.).

When I create the chart in Excel all x-axis values are equally spread.

Is this even possible in Excel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the series (0,1,2,4,8,16) as Horizontal Category (Axis) Labels, Excel will always equally spread the values unless you select one of the **Scatter chart** types.

After selecting a Scatter chart for your data, you will see that your x-axis labels will spread according to their values.

Answer (score 2):

Because by default, the series (0,1,2,4,8,16) are **Category labels** rather than **values** in Excel, so no matter how the big the number is, they will be equally spread.

What you want to do is to make the X-axis linear, so instead of considering the series as category labels, they will be seen as real numbers.

Mepher above already answered how you can do this in Excel. But if you want another more versatile solution, you could try to use an Excel add-in called FunFun, it allows you to use JavaScript directly in Excel so that you could use powerful libraries like D3.js or Chart.js to make different charts.

In the link below, I made a chart with FunFun playground, you could see the labels X-axis are **spreading linearly** according to their values.

https://www.funfun.io/1/edit/5a27fb06cf76561801b73335

You could also link this result directly to your Excel by URL. Here are some screenshots of how it looks like in Excel.

[image]

[image]

***Disclosure: I'm a developer of Funfun***

Comment: Another ancient post : are you pulling these out for a publicity or marketing drive???

Comment: Hi Mike, I just added a [disclose](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) to the answer :) It is indeed an ancient post and with more than 4000 views. I wanted to show my solution (perhaps another possibility) to people who may have similar problems. And I also wrote specific and working JavaScript codes (as people may write VBA code) to answer this specific question.